# jQuery: get value of clicked element

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code:

```
<tr class="editField">
  <td>abc</td>
  <td>123</td>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="editField">
  <td>dfg</td>
  <td>456</td>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And then I have this javascript to open a dialog with jQuery:

```
$( ".editField" ).click(function() {
        alert(...); // should get me 123
});
```

Suppose I click on first `tr` and I would get the content of second `td` (i.e 123), what should I write?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd suggest, given your current mark-up:

```
$( ".editField" ).click(function() {
        alert($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
});
```

But, while this works in the given example, it'd be much easier (and subsequently far more reliable) to add some defining attribute to the element from which you wish to recover the 'value', such as the class-name 'value', giving HTML like so:

```
<tr class="editField">
  <td>abc</td>
  <td class="value">123</td>
</tr>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$( ".editField" ).click(function() {
        alert($(this).find('td.value').text());
});
```

Or, of course, if the 'value' will always be the *last* `td` element of any given row (of the relevant class), then you could instead use:

```
$( ".editField" ).click(function() {
        alert($(this).find('td:last').text());
});
```

Incidentally, please note that your HTML is malformed, you have a surplus `</td>` after the last cell in both rows of your sample code.

References:

- [`eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:last` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: I just cannot compete with yours ;-) +1 and delete

Comment: Oh, I'm more than certain you're able to compete! Perhaps far too chivalrous and noble-minded to stoop to so petty a level though..! =) Also, may I say thank you for the syntax-tidy? Much appreciated!

Comment: i need to get an object from the click, can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$( ".editField" ).click(function() {

    var clickedValue = $(this).find('td:first').next().text();

alert(clickedValue );    

});
```

fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/9cRRj/8/

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(function () {
        $(".Cartbtn").click(function () {
            var temp = {
                "Id": $(this).data("itemid"),
                "Name": $(this).data("itemname"),
                "Price": $(this).data("itemprice"),
                "Quantity": $(this).data("itemqty"),
                "ImageUrl": $(this).data("itemimgurl"),
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).bind("click", function (e) {
    $(e.target).closest("li").toggleClass("highlight");
    alert($(event.target).text());
});
```

this will directly give you the selected element id. 
$(event.target).text(); 
will give you the selected element text within a second.