# Update URL in one function on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I have a Node.js website using the Pug templating engine where there is an option to change the language the website is displayed in.

To date this has all been rather hard coded in, with the language switchers in my navbar displayed as:

```
li.nav-item.active
    a(href="#" id="to_en") EN &nbsp
    a(href="#" id='to_kyr') | KG &nbsp
    a(href="#" id='to_ru') | RU &nbsp
```

When these values were clicked on the following jQuery functions ran to change the URL to be the new language:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var current = location.pathname;
    var ru_url = current.replace('/en', '/ru');
    $("#to_ru").prop('href', ru_url);
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var current = location.pathname;
    var kg_url = current.replace('/en', '/kg');
    $("#to_kyr").prop('href', kg_url);
});
```

I'm now trying to replace this with a generalised function which picks up the current language and the language selected and then performs the same operation. Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187407/jquery-get-value-of-clicked-element), I've tried adding in class specifiers as can be seen below, but I'm not sure this will work as I don't want to have to specify which language I've selected each time.

```
li.nav-item.active
    a(class="change_lang" href="#" id="to_en") EN &nbsp
    a(class="change_lang" href="#" id='to_kyr') | KG &nbsp
    a(class="change_lang" href="#" id='to_ru') | RU &nbsp
```

I also have the current language stored as a jQuery variable which I can use to find the part of the URL to replace, shown below (where #{lang} could be "/en" for example). Is there a way to change the URL dynamically getting the value clicked on?

current.replace('#{lang}', 'lang_to_change_to')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) functions to create something along these lines...

```js
function getCurrentUrl() {
  //TODO: for demo purposes I've replaced this line: "return location.pathname;"
  return "http://example.com/en/index.htm";
}

function getActiveLanguage() {
  //TODO: You should search the URL for the language text, e.g. "/en" or "/kr" to determine the current language.
  return "en";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  const currentUrl = getCurrentUrl();
  const activeLanguage = getActiveLanguage();

  // Loop over each element with class "change_lang"
  $(".change_lang").each(function(index, element) {
    // Get the "data-language" attribute value for each of these elements.
    const language = $(element).data("language");

    // Your original code to change the links
    var url = currentUrl.replace('/' + activeLanguage, '/' + language);
    $(element).prop('href', url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="change_lang" data-language="en" href="#" id="to_en">EN</a>
<a class="change_lang" data-language="kg" href="#" id='to_kyr'>KG</a>
<a class="change_lang" data-language="ru" href="#" id='to_ru'>RU</a>
```